# Center align a p element within a div or td

Tags: css

I want the paragraph to be centered, but the text within the paragraph to be left aligned. For example I can not use `text-align: center` because that center aligns the actual text. How can I do this using css? Im sure there is a simple solution but I am new to css and I can't find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the paragraph a width and margin of auto: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zukf3baL/)

```
p {
    width: 300px; //or a percentage width (just not auto)
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Or as you asked for in the comment - with padding: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zukf3baL/1/)

```
p {
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    text-align: width;
}
```

Comment: this is a great solution, would it be possible to do something like this using padding rather than margins?

Comment: I can not let p's width be adjustable, it must have a constant width e.g 300px

Comment: Then you will need to use the first solution (or put it in a wrapper- using the same solution). You can always add additional padding if desired too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class=center_div>
  <p>text here</p> 
</div>

<style>
.center_div
{
  width: 50%
  margin: 0 auto
  background-color: red;
}


.center_div p
{
  text-align: left
}
</style>
```

jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pvozycku/